# How to make a language homoiconic

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming

According to [this article](https://brandonbyars.com/2008/02/12/understanding-syntactic-macros/) the following line of Lisp code prints "Hello world" to standard output.

```
(format t "hello, world")
```

Lisp, which is a [homoiconic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), can treat code as data in this way:

> Now imagine that we wrote the following macro:
>
> `(defmacro backwards (expr) (reverse expr))`
>
> backwards is the name of the macro, which takes an expression
>   (represented as a list), and reverses it. Here’s "Hello, world" again,
>   this time using the macro:
>
> `(backwards ("hello, world" t format))`
>
> When the Lisp compiler sees that line of code, it looks at the first
>   atom in the list (`backwards`), and notices that it names a macro. It
>   passes the unevaluated list `("hello, world" t format)` to the macro,
>   which rearranges the list to `(format t "hello, world")`. The resulting
>   list replaces the macro expression, and it is what will be evaluated
>   at run-time. The Lisp environment will see that its first atom
>   (`format`) is a function, and evaluate it, passing it the rest of the
>   arguments.

In Lisp achieving this task is easy (correct me if I'm wrong) because code is implemented as list ([s-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)?).

Now take a look at this OCaml (which is not a homoiconic language) snippet:

```
let print () =
    let message = "Hello world" in
    print_endline message
;;
```

Imagine you want to add homoiconicity to OCaml, which uses a much more complex syntax compared to Lisp. How would you do that? Does the language has to have a particularly easy syntax to achieve homoiconicity?

**EDIT**: from [this topic](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1810480) I found [another way to achieve homoiconicity](http://web.archive.org/web/20080212010904/http://hackety.org/2008/01/05/ioHasAVeryCleanMirror.html) which is different from Lisp's: the one implemented in the [io language](http://iolanguage.org/). It may partially answer this question.

> Here, let’s start with a simple block:
>
> ```
> Io> plus := block(a, b, a + b)
> ==> method(a, b, 
>         a + b
>     )
> Io> plus call(2, 3)
> ==> 5
> ```
>
> Okay, so the block works. The plus block added two numbers.
>
> Now let’s do some introspection on this little fellow.
>
> ```
> Io> plus argumentNames
> ==> list("a", "b")
> Io> plus code
> ==> block(a, b, a +(b))
> Io> plus message name
> ==> a
> Io> plus message next
> ==> +(b)
> Io> plus message next name
> ==> +
> ```
>
> Hot holy cold mold. Not only can you get the names of the block
>   params. And not only can you get a string of the block’s complete
>   source code. You can sneak into the code and traverse the messages
>   inside. And most amazing of all: it’s awfully easy and natural. True
>   to Io’s quest. Ruby’s mirror can’t see any of that.
>
> But, whoa whoa, hey now, don’t touch that dial.
>
> ```
> Io> plus message next setName("-")
> ==> -(b)
> Io> plus
> ==> method(a, b, 
>         a - b
>     )
> Io> plus call(2, 3)
> ==> -1
> ```

Comment: You might want to have a look at how [Scala did its macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

Comment: @Bergi Scala has a new approach to macros: [scala.meta](http://scalameta.org/).

Comment: I've always though homoiconicity is overrated.  In any sufficiently powerful language you can always define a tree structure that mirrors the structure of the language itself, and utility functions can be written to translate to and from the source language (and/or a compiled form) as required.  Yes, it's *slightly* easier in LISPs, but given that (a) the vast majority of programming work should *not* be metaprogramming and (b) LISP has sacrificed language clarity to make this possible, I don't think the tradeoff is worth it.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta You are right, but the key advantage of MP is that MP enables abstractions *without run-time penalty*. Thus MP resolves the tension between abstraction and performance, albeit at the cost of increasing language complexity. Is it worth it? I'd say the fact that *all* major PLs have MP extensions indicates that a lot of working programmers find  the trade-offs MP offers useful.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta I think the benefit of homoiconicity is more psychological, related to reason-ability, than anything. Because the the programmer can see and read the code which is the data structure he would inject to whatever macro function at runtime. Instead of having to be familiar with the tree structure that the language uses to represent it internally, to be able to code the macro function correctly. Because the data and the code represent that tree structure inherently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make any language homoiconic. Essentially you do this by 'mirroring' the language (meaning for any language constructor you add a corresponding representation of that constructor as data, think AST). You also need to add a couple of additional operations like quoting and unquoting. That's more or less it.

Lisp had that early on because of its easy syntax, but W. Taha's MetaML family of languages showed that it's possible to do for any language.

The whole process is outlined in [Modelling homogeneous generative meta-programming](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06568). A more lightweight introduction to the same material is [here](http://users.sussex.ac.uk/~mfb21/publications/mp-slides/slides.pdf).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. "mirroring" is related to the second part of the question (homoiconicity in io lang), right?

Comment: @Ignus I'm not sure I fully understand your remark. The purpose of homoiconicity is to enable the treatment of code as data. That means any form of code must have a representation as data. There are several ways of doing this (e.g. ASTs quasi-quotes, using types to distinguish code from data as done by the light-weight modular staging approach), but all require a doubling/mirroring of the language syntax in some form.

Comment: I assume @Ignus would benefit from looking at MetaOCaml then? Does being "homoiconic" just mean being quotable then? I assume that multi-stage languages like MetaML and MetaOCaml go further?

Comment: @StevenShaw MetaOCaml is very interesting, especially Oleg's new [BER MetaOCaml](http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/MetaOCaml.html). However, it is somewhat restricted in that it performs only run-time meta-programming, and represents code only via quasi-quotes which is not as expressive as ASTs.

Answer (score 7):

The Ocaml compiler is written in Ocaml itself, so *certainly* there is a way to manipulate Ocaml ASTs in Ocaml.

One might imagine adding a built-in type `ocaml_syntax` to the language, and having a `defmacro` built-in function, which takes an input of type, say

```
f : ocaml_syntax -> ocaml_syntax
```

Now what is the *type* of `defmacro`? Well that really depends on the input, as even if `f` is the identity function, the type of the resulting piece of code is dependent on the piece of syntax passed in.

This problem does not arise in lisp, since the language is dynamically typed, and no type needs to be ascribed to the macro itself at compile time. One solution would be to have

```
defmacro : (ocaml_syntax -> ocaml_syntax) -> 'a
```

which would allow the macro to be used in *any* context. But this is unsafe, of course, it would allow a `bool` to be used in stead of a `string`, crashing the program at run-time.

The only principled solution in a statically-typed language would be to have *dependent types* in which the result type of `defmacro` would be dependent on the input. Things get quite complicated at this point though, and I would start by pointing you at the nice [dissertation](http://en.itu.dk/~/media/EN/Research/PhD-Programme/PhD-defences/2016/PhD-thesis-final-version-David-Raymond-Christiansen-pdf.pdf?la=en) by David Raymond Christiansen.

In conclusion: having complicated syntax is not an issue, since there are many ways to represent the syntax inside the language, and possibly use meta-programing like a `quote` operation to embed the "simple" syntax into the internal `ocaml_syntax`.

The issue is making this well-typed, in particular having a run-time macro mechanism that does not allow for type errors.

Having a *compile-time* mechanism for macros in a language like Ocaml is possible of course, see e.g. [MetaOcaml](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~taha/MetaOCaml/).

Also possibly useful: [Jane street on meta-programing in Ocaml](https://blogs.janestreet.com/extension-points-or-how-ocaml-is-becoming-more-like-lisp/)

Comment: MetaOCaml has runtime-meta-programming, not compile-time meta-programming. Also MetaOCaml's typing system doesn't have dependent types. (MetaOCaml was also found to be type-unsound!) Template Haskell has an interesting intermediate approach: every stage is type-safe, but when entering a new stage, we must re-do type-checking. This works really well in practise in my experience, and you don't loose the benefits of type-safety at the final (run-time) stage.

Comment: @cody it is possible to have metaprogramming in OCaml also with [Extension Points](https://whitequark.org/blog/2014/04/16/a-guide-to-extension-points-in-ocaml/), right?

Comment: @Ignus I'm afraid I don't know about much about Extension Points, though I do reference it in the link to the Jane Street blog.

Comment: My C compiler is written in C, but that doesn't mean you can manipulate the AST in C...

Comment: @MartinBerger as far as I can tell, MetaOcaml has several "stages", so it doesn't make sense to talk about *the* compile time or *the* run time. But I'm not sure at which point the pieces of code created by the previous stages are being type-checked.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You can certainly manipulate the AST *of a different program than the one currently running* in C, or any language.

Comment: @immibis: Obviously, but if that's what he meant then that statement is both vacuous and unrelated to the question...

Comment: @cody MetaOCaml has an arbitrary number of stages, all of which happen at run-time. Type-checking happens at compile-time, and guarantees soundness of all future stages. In contrast, Template Haskel does compile-time meta-programming, and each compile-time stage is type-checked separately.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft the question was: "Does the language has to have a particulary easy syntax to achieve homoiconicity?". The answer in Ocaml, as in C is *no*, as I tried to explain.

Answer (score 2):

As an example consider F# (based on OCaml). F# is not fully homoiconic, but supports getting the code of a function as an AST under certain circumstances.

In F#, your `print` would be represented as an `Expr` that is printed as:

```
Let (message, Value ("Hello world"), Call (None, print_endline, [message]))
```

To highlight the structure better, here is an alternative way how you could create the same `Expr`:

```f#
let messageVar = Var("message", typeof<string>)
let expr = Expr.Let(messageVar,
                    Expr.Value("Hello world"),
                    Expr.Call(print_endline_method, [Expr.Var(messageVar)]))
```

Comment: I did not understand it. You mean that F# lets you "build" the AST of an expression and then execute it? If so, what's the difference with languages that lets you use the `eval(<string>)` function? ([According to many resources, having eval function is different from having homoiconicity](https://blogs.oracle.com/blue/entry/homoiconic_languages) - is it the reason why you said F# is not fully homoiconic?)

Comment: @Ignus You can build the AST yourself, or you can let the compiler do it. Homoiconicity ["allows all code in the language to be accessed and transformed as data"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity). In F#, you can access *some* code as data. (For example, you need to mark `print` with the `[<ReflectedDefinition>]` attribute.)